# Use JRuby (or IronRuby) to boots performance of Rails on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, jruby, ironruby

I am currently developing Rails on a Windows laptop, but it runs very slowly. Would it be worthwhile to try running rails on JRuby or IronRuby to speed up performance?

Comment: Run them all and test which is fastest. Real results is better than guessing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ruby 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 don't worry about that, it's fast as others or even faster. Also notice that java applications tends to use a lot of memmory.

The thing is that in development your app is reloaded in each request, in production it will be loaded only at server startup.

To test it try to run your app in production environment, and maybe you should use other server like [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/).

```
thin start -e production
```

Also if this does not help. Maybe you should think about cache, create new indexes or even change to a better data base (maybe you are using sqlite). But I doubt that changing to Jruby or IronRuby will help you that much.

Comment: the loading of the actual pages isn't that slow, but running rails commands is, even simple ones.